# Appending text to the end of a line only if it does not exist using ansible or bash

Tags: bash, sed, ansible

I am trying to edit NCPA configuration to allow some of the plugins I use to run as a sudo. For this to work I need to add a comma separated list of plugins to a line in ncpa.cfg with directive "run_with_sudo =". Problem is that I want to add multiple plugins, but not all at once, otherwise I would just use sed or lineinfile. I want to do this via ansible playbook either using some specific module or though shell module as the NCPA configuration happens during the provisioning of the given machine.

I am upgrading from NRPE where you would just define the command with a sudo in the nrpe.cfg itself so it was easier. But I am now upgrading to NCPA and I want to reuse most of the nrpe playbook I use to install checks onto the destination machine. And only problem is the addition of plugins to one line.

So what I want to do exactly,

1. I have this line in ncpa.cfg

> run_with_sudo =

2. Task runs and adds plugin to the run_with_sudo

> run_with_sudo = some_plugin_1.sh,

3. This happens few more times as playbook goes over other plugins that require sudo

> run_with_sudo = some_plugin_1.sh,some_plugin_2.sh,some_plugin_3.sh,

When I rerun the playbook, nothing should change. So I want to basically append a text to the end of this line, but only if it is not already there. So I need to somehow check if the line with "run_with_sudo =" contains a specific plugin and if it doesn't add it to the end of the line.

Is there a reasonable way to do this?

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html

Comment: Do you need a bash script who receives the ncpa.cfg location and the plugin name as parameters and perform the explained task?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

plugin="$1"
shift

awk -v plugin="$plugin" '
{ sub(/\r$/,"") }
$1 == "run_with_sudo" {
    present = 0
    n = split($3,plugins,",")
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        if ( plugins[i] == plugin ) {
            present = 1
            break
        }
    }
    if ( !present ) {
        $0 = $0 plugin ","
    }
}
{ print $0 }
' "${@:--}"
```

```
$ cat file
run_with_sudo = some_plugin_1.sh,some_plugin_2.sh,some_plugin_3.sh,
```

```
$ ./tst.sh some_plugin_2.sh file
run_with_sudo = some_plugin_1.sh,some_plugin_2.sh,some_plugin_3.sh,
```

```
$ ./tst.sh some_plugin_4.sh file
run_with_sudo = some_plugin_1.sh,some_plugin_2.sh,some_plugin_3.sh,some_plugin_4.sh,
```